# Why does HTML form menu open URL in same window/tab?

Tags: html, forms

I want the menu URLs to open in a new tab/window, I do not want it to overwrite the current page with the desired URL. Message title is covered up by code block “help”. Just to show: I use `_blank`, the browsers ignore it.

```html
<FORM name="Menu_1a">
  <SELECT name="URL" onChange="if(options[selectedIndex].value)
    window.location.href=(options[selectedIndex].value) " style="background-color: #CCFF99; font-weight: bold;">
    <option value="" selected="selected" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">---Select --></option>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/index_acco.html" target="_self">Reset this menu</OPTION>
    <!-- this works, except it replaces page instead of opening new -->
    <OPTION value="http://www.jakob-schlaepfer.ch/en/decor/collection-a-m/" target="_blank">Background</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://lyricstranslate.com/en/amor-eterno-love-eternal.html">Amor Eterno - Lyrics</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QuXKirNX3I">Amor Eterno - R. Durcal</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsww/Maps/10/260_15.php">Quakes Acapulco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://www.emsc-csem.org/#2w/" target="_blank">Quakes terremoto</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://acapulcodejuarez.olx.com.mx/item_page.php?Id=280315985&ts=1321310362/" target="_blank">Advertising - Emilio</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/sndass/ezlxsndass.html" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">Soundassistent for Limex Midi</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/sndass/ezlxsndass.html" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">Klangassistent f&uuml;r Limex Midi</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/lx_1.htm/#top0">Limex Midi Erfahrungen</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="" style="background-color: Yellow; font-weight: bold;">01234567890123456</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Code looks alright, have you tested it on google chrome ?

Comment: The code above does open a new page in `window`, which is the current window. You say you use `_blank`, but, ehm, where?

Comment: I can not find where to edit my post.<br>I can not find where / how to insert code.<br>

Comment: __actual live page: http://ezaca.tripod.com the example uses MENU_A 1 on page

Answer (score 0):

If you can submit the `form` in a new window you need to add attribute `target="_blank"` to the form.

> The target attribute specifies a name or a keyword that indicates where to display the response that is received after submitting the form.
>
> The target attribute defines a name of, or keyword for, a browsing context (e.g. tab, window, or inline frame).

<sub>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp</sub>

```html
<FORM name="Menu_1a" target="_blank">
  <SELECT name="URL" onChange="if(options[selectedIndex].value)
    window.location.href=(options[selectedIndex].value) " style="background-color: #CCFF99; font-weight: bold;">
    <option value="" selected="selected" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">---Select --></option>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/index_acco.html" target="_self">Reset this menu</OPTION>
    <!-- this works, except it replaces page instead of opening new -->
    <OPTION value="http://www.jakob-schlaepfer.ch/en/decor/collection-a-m/" target="_blank">Background</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://lyricstranslate.com/en/amor-eterno-love-eternal.html">Amor Eterno - Lyrics</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QuXKirNX3I">Amor Eterno - R. Durcal</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/recenteqsww/Maps/10/260_15.php">Quakes Acapulco</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://www.emsc-csem.org/#2w/" target="_blank">Quakes terremoto</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://acapulcodejuarez.olx.com.mx/item_page.php?Id=280315985&ts=1321310362/" target="_blank">Advertising - Emilio</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/sndass/ezlxsndass.html" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">Soundassistent for Limex Midi</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/sndass/ezlxsndass.html" target="_blank" style="background-color: #FFCC99; font-weight: bold;">Klangassistent f&uuml;r Limex Midi</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="http://ezaca.tripod.com/acco/lx_1.htm/#top0">Limex Midi Erfahrungen</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="" style="background-color: Yellow; font-weight: bold;">01234567890123456</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Comment: I marked the code, used ctrl+k. It looks different compared to previous layout.?? 2016.07.26. The operation of this forum is still rather strange to me in spite of 20 years online experience. I hope my additions are not lost, I can not find a submit button for the edited text.